# How to style a static page in rails 4 app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, static-pages

I want to style a static page to be as a landing page for the rails app.
The static page is from the StaticPagesController.
But the problem is when I add the class in the static page (home.html.erb)
and in the application.css add the styling it doesn't use the styles.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What layout are you using? (check for app/views/layouts) usually it's application.html.erb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the `application.css` to `application.scss` because for rails 4 is better to work with `.scss` extension.

Then, DON'T write your code directly in your `application.scss` file, is a really bad practice.

Import your `.scss` files (without the extension) For example:

```
*= require_tree .
 = require rails_bootstrap_forms
 *= require_self
*/

@import "yourfilename";
```

If you are using `.sass` extension, then you must include this line in your `config/application.rb` file:

```
config.sass.preferred_syntax = :sass
```

This is because rails takes by default .css or .scss extension instead of .sass extension.

If you deleted the content of the `application.scss` you have to restore it too.

Comment: Yes, actually is like a Must. 

Application takes every single stylesheets. 

But your issue is different. You are using .sass extension.

In your application.rb file add this line:

config.sass.preferred_syntax = :sass

Rails use by default .css or .scss not .sass extension

Answer (score 0):

This should be the file. `\app\views\layouts\application.html.erb`

You can add link to your stylesheet in the head section.

or

You can `@include` your custom css file into `application.css` file which should be located at `\app\assets\stylesheets\`